# StyleCop Analyzers: SA1633 "Missing file header" rule for AssemblyInfo.cs files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stylecop

I'm wondering whether the [SA1633](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1633.md) StyleCop Analyzers rule makes sense for `AssemblyInfo.cs` files that are auto-generated by the Visual Studio.

The `AssemblyInfo.cs` files already contain the copyright, company, etc. information. So it seems kind of like adding the standard file header according to the StyleCop suggestion is nothing more than a duplicate.

So, should this rule better be suppressed or is there any valid use case for that?

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/2086072.aspx?StyleCop+ignore+AssemblyInfo+cs+

Comment: It's not auto-generated.  Well, it is, but you should change the contents to be valid for your requirements (or delete entirely), therefore it's source-code for your project and then needs a valid header.   Maybe requiring a header on all files is unnecessary (I've not seen one on any C# project for over 5 years)?